# Overwrite OnFileOpen and OnFileSave function - registry is not updated?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a little problem that I do not know how to solved:

I am writing a program that involves data serialization. I decided to override the `OnFileOpen` and `OnFileSave` function because I wanted to modify the File Dialog Box when open/save the file.

My problem is: after I load the file, the program title still remains 'Untitled' and the 'Recent File' list under the 'File' menu bar is not updated either.

I suppose I need to add some code to update the registry? But I struggle to find the solution of it...

Thank you all for the helps! Highly appreciated!

Here are my `OnFileOpen` and `OnFileSave` code:

```
void CXXXDoc::OnFileOpen()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here

    TCHAR szFilters[]= _T("XXX Type Files (*.xxx)|*.xxx|All Files (*.*)|*.*||");
    CFileDialog fileDlg(TRUE, _T("xxx"), _T("*.xxx"), OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST, szFilters);
    if(fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        CFile oldFile;
        ASSERT (oldFile != NULL);
        oldFile.Open(fileDlg.GetPathName(), CFile::modeRead | CFile::shareExclusive);
        FilePathName = fileDlg.GetPathName();
        SetTitle(FilePathName);
        CArchive loadArchive(&oldFile, CArchive::load | CArchive::bNoFlushOnDelete); // Create the archive to load data, the archive must be closed manually after the loading process      
        Serialize(loadArchive);
        loadArchive.Close();
        oldFile.Close();        
        UpdateAllViews(0);

    }

}

void CXXXDoc::OnFileSave()
{
            CFile newfile;
        ASSERT (newfile != NULL);
        newfile.Open(FilePathName, CFile::modeWrite);
        CArchive saveArchive(&newfile, CArchive::store);   // Create the archive to save data,
        Serialize(saveArchive);
        saveArchive.Close();
        newfile.Close();
}
```

Comment: Just in case you want to look it up or search for it: the term is "override", not "overwrite".

Answer (score 1):

To keep the most recently used (MRU) list updated, you need to call `CWinApp::AddToRecentFileList` ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yzykxyk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). So, for your `OnFileOpen`, you might do this:

```
AfxGetApp()->AddToRecentFileList(FilePathName);
```

As the remarks in MSDN say:

> You should call the **LoadStdProfileSettings** member function to load the
>   current MRU file list before you use this member function.
>
> The framework calls this member function when it opens a file or
>   executes the Save As command to save a file with a new name.

Comment: Thank you for the help Roger! 

At this stage I use the SetTitle(FilePathName) and AddToRecentFileList(FilePathName) functions to get around the issue.

However, I realise another problem: When I tried to load the file through the Recent File List, the following error occurs:

Debug Assertion Failed!
File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wingdi.cpp Line: 1119
For information on how your program can cause an assertion failuer, see ....etc.

Can you possibly tell me the reason for this error message?

Comment: @Kent that sounds unrelated to this - looking at my VS2012 sources, it's asserting in `CGdiObject::Attach` because you are attaching an object that hasn't been previously detached. Maybe your document clean-up is not sufficient - debugger should show the call stack so you can isolate your code. Post a new question with the code concerned if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Roger, I will have another look of it.

I just found it very weird because this error message will not appear if I open the file via the normal "Menu->File->Open" steps. The error message pop out whenever I tried to load the file through the Recent File List and Drag/Drop function.

So I am doubting that maybe there is something wrong in my FileSave/FileOpen overriding functions...